# Получить доступ к дочернему элементу в переборе

Tags: jquery

Собираю все элементы класса:

```
$('#search').click(function(){

    var searchLabel = $('.search_label');

    searchLabel.each(function(indx, element){

    });
}
```

Получаю `label` с дочерними элементами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь нужно получить из перебираемых элементов содержимое `span`. `find()` не работает, выдаёт ошибку что нет такой функции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не `element.find(...)`, a `$(element).find(...)`:

```
$('#search').click(function() {
  var searchLabel = $('.search_label');
  searchLabel.each(function(indx, element) {
    var childSpan = $(element).find('span');
    console.log(childSpan.length, childSpan.text());
  });
}
```

Параметр `element` - это узел DOM-дерева, а не объект-обертка jQuery.

https://api.jquery.com/each/